# Gcc 13.1.0 macOS Sonoma not compiling Ada or any languages on Intel or M1 Macs

Tags: macos, gcc, ada

I just upgraded to macOS Sonoma on my Intel and M1 Macs, and Gcc and Alire cannot compile simple Ada programs or any others so I suspect it's a compatibility issue. I am using Gcc 13.1.0 aarch64 and x86_64 on the MacBook Pro/Air M1 and MacBook Pro Core i9 respectively. The error I see among others is "-macosx_version_min has been renamed to -macosx_version_min" also: "exited with code 4" Since I cannot compile Ada programs which is most important, is there a workaround or hack until there are upgraded versions to fix it? The same errors are present on both the Intel and M1 Macs, and I had no issues at all on macOS Ventura.

I tried using Gcc 13.1.0 aarch64 and x86_64 on my MacBook M1s and only the x86_64 version on my Intel MacBook Pro Core i9. I tried using Alire with it's native compilers on both type Macs and its matching gprbuild version. The same errors are present using the terminal editing with "nano" and compiling with "gnatmake" or Gnat Studio using the Gcc 13.1.0 toolchain. It obviously is a compatibility issue between Gcc/Alire and macOS Sonoma. It's not just Ada "Hello, World!", but C and C++ "Hello, World!"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, with Sonoma, Apple have provided an updated Xcode version 15.0 (and Command Line Tools) which breaks the linking process. We live in hope that a version 15.1 fixing the problem comes out soon.

Unfortunately, you can’t reinstall the Command Line Tools version 14.3 on Sonoma, because it’s "too early". The same probably applies to Xcode.

If you’re running Time Machine, try restoring `/Applications/Xcode.app` (or `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, whichever you’re using) to a state before they got "upgraded"; and then resist System Settings’ trying to upgrade again.

If you’re using `gnatmake`,

```
$ gnatmake foo.adb -largs -Wl,-ld_classic
```

Similarly, if you’re using `gprbuild`,

```
$ gprbuild -P foo.gpr -largs -Wl,-ld_classic
```

or you could modify the `package Linker` in your GPR to include the equivalent, like

```
package Linker is
   for Switches ("ada") use ("-Wl,-ld_classic");
end Linker;
```

With `alire`,

```
$ alr build -- -largs -Wl,-ld_classic
```

---

These suggestions do have the air of magical incantations.

To expand,

- `-largs` tells `gnatmake`/`gprbuild` to send what follows to the linking phase of the build (`gnatlink`).
- `-Wl` tells `gcc` (which is invoked by `gnatlink` to supervise the linking) to send what follows to the linker (`ld`), with commas replaced by spaces; so `-Wl,-ld_classic` means that the linker is invoked with `ld -ld_classic`. If you want to see the linker command line, use `-Wl,-ld_classic,-v`, which is sent as `ld -ld_classic -v` (with lots of other parameters!)

---

*(or you could ask some kindly soul who still has version 14.3 to give you a copy of `ld`)*

Comment: I may have hit the wrong button, on the useful answer If I did I do apologize but I tried these commands but I'm getting errors such as unknown option -Wl did you mean -W? And it still says link failed. I may have missed a command parameter.

Comment: No, my mistake; there should be a space between `-largs` and `-Wl`. Added some notes, hope they’ll help

Comment: I entered: gnatmake main.adb -largs -W1, -ld_classic    I still get mostly the same errors:   -macosx_version_min has been renamed to -macos_version_min   ld: file not found collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status gnatlink error when calling /opt/gcc-13.1.0-aarch64/bin/gcc gnatmake *** link failed

Comment: It’s `-Wl,-ld_classic` - the character after the `W` is a lower-case L, there’s no space after the comma. Oh, and don’t worry about the `-macosx_version_min` warning, it’s corrected in GCC 14

Comment: I tried both, my mistake I was doing lowercase l, but the error now is ld: file not found. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status error when calling the directory to gcc

Answer (score 2):

I found a working solution! I have downloaded the Apple Command Line Tools 15.1 Beta from the Apple Developer Site and it works with the only warning being: "ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lgcc'   I am now able to compile, link, and run Ada, C, C++ programs. All of these languages have the same compiler warning. I always felt uncomfortable running beta software, but because it's not for anything real it's okay. I thank you very much for all of your help, and hopefully Apple will get 15.1 out soon. Also, I hope when 15.1 is released it will just upgrade all of the beta software and I won't have to remove or uninstall it manually.

Comment: I had to switch to the command-line tools installed with my Xcode-beta using 
`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/`